# Clickable menu from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a menu from mysql database.

```
CREATE TABLE category(
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO category VALUES
(1,'ELECTRONICS',0),
(2,'TELEVISIONS',1),
(3,'COMPUTER',1),
(4,'DELL',3),
(5,'LCD',2),
(6,'PLASMA',2),
(7,'FLASH',6),
(8,'BIKE',0),
(9,'MOTORCYCLE',8),
(10,'SCOOTER',8),
(11,'BAJAJ',9),
(12,'MAHINDRA',10);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9e33c/1)

```
    <div>
       <form id="my_form1" action="" method="post" >
<?php 

$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT 
    t1.product AS lev1
    FROM category AS t1
    LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.id
    WHERE t1.parent_id = '0' group by t1.id");

    while($sql_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                            ?>

<a name="aqwse" href="#" onclick=""><?php echo $sql_result['lev1']; ?><br></a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>  
</form>
    </div>
```

With the above query I am able to get only the first level. How will I get second, or third or fourth  level that I have shown in the sql query with sqlfiddle. Suppose when I click serially on ELECTRONICS  >>    TELEVISIONS >>  PLASMA  >> FLASH.   I failed to create the php  form.

Comment: Your SQLFiddle shows that you have the SELECT parts `lev2`, `lev3` and `lev4`. Why have you removed them from your query in PHP? It looks like you want to use `$sql_result['lev2']` to `$sql_result['lev4']`. Please edit your question with the explanation why your SQL query in php differs from the SQL query in your SQLFiddle.